# userInputsgirl is being called a variable even though its a class

Tags: c#

Im a beginner in C# and still learning. While coding, i am stuck at this line of code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            userInputsBoy userInputsBoy = new userInputsBoy(); //This particular line
            userInputsGirl userInputsGirl = new userInputsGirl();
            Console.Write("Enter your name in : ");
            userInputsBoy.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter your age here : ");
            userInputsBoy.age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter your personality here : ");
            userInputsBoy.personality = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(userInputsGirl.name + " " + userInputsBoy.age + " " + userInputsBoy.personality);
        }
```

and getting this error

```
'userInputsGirl' is a variable but is used like a type
```

The classes:

```
        class userInputsBoy {
            public string name;
            public int age;
            public string personality;

            public userInputsBoy() {
                name = "";
                age = 0;
                personality = "";
            }
        class userInputsGirl {
            public string name;
            public int age;
            public string personality;

            public userInputsGirl() {
                name = "";
                age = 0;
                personality = "";
            
            }
```

Im also pretty new to stack overflow so, yeah. All help is aprreciated. <3

Comment: You have correctly outlined the situation and the resulting error - very good. Now, it seems your class and your variable have the very same name (down to the casing of characters). How is the compiler supposed to know which occurrence of `userInputsGirl` refers to the variable and which one refers to the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines are confusing both you and the compiler:

```
userInputsBoy userInputsBoy = new userInputsBoy();
userInputsGirl userInputsGirl = new userInputsGirl();
```

In each of those lines you are trying to define a variable with the *exact same name* as a class.  Give them different names.  Ideally, in C# classes should start with capital letters:

```
class UserInputsBoy {
  //...
}
```

Then you can use your lowercase names for the variables:

```
UserInputsBoy userInputsBoy = new UserInputsBoy();
```

This is at least more idiomatic for C# naming standards.  Aside from that though, feel free to give them clearly different names to avoid confusion.  For example:

```
UserInputsBoy boy = new UserInputsBoy();
```

This is also a good time for you to ask yourself why you even have these two classes, and why they are called `UserInputsBoy` and `UserInputsGirl`.  These classes are *identical* and both seem to simply describe a "person", so why not just have that?

```
class Person {
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string personality;

    public Person() {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
        personality = "";
    }
}
```

And:

```
Person boy = new Person();
Person girl = new Person();
```

Semantically this quickly becomes *much more clear* about what you're describing, which will make it easier for you to maintain an understanding of the code you're writing and continue to develop that code.

As an aside, you'll also want to start favoring properties over public fields:

```
class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Are { get; set; }
    public string Personality { get; set; }

    public Person() {
        Name = "";
        Age = 0;
        Personality = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually haven't think about making your answer. I'm pretty new to c#, so kinda stupid. But your answer definitely makes sense. Thank you ♥️

Comment: @amirulpanda: It's a good early lesson to know that naming and semantics are very important in programming.  Any given class, variable, etc. should simply and succinctly self-describe what it is.  Over time, the code itself should generally read like a simple step-by-step story telling what it does.